# React Native Root Element, deciding on async call

Tags: react-native

I'm currently writing an App in React-Native, which also includes a login. I use AsyncStorage for saving the credentials. Now I want to show the user different Screens (Navigators) whether he is logged in or not.
To check if he is logged in, I check if there are credentials in the AsyncStorage, and the function to check this returns a promise. So now when I call the function in my  component, it wont wait until the promise has resolved and I don't have any idea on how to solve. I tried with  but this also failed. Maybe you have any idea. Below my code. Thanks

```
import 'react-native-gesture-handler'
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native'
import AppNavigation from './navigation/AppNavigation.js'
import { ThemeProvider, Text } from 'react-native-magnus'
import { useState, useEffect, useCallback, Suspense} from 'react'
import {React } from 'react'
import getNutrientsCompare from './utils/getNutrientsCompare.js'
import getLoginSession from './utils/getLoginSession.js'
import Login from './pages/Login.js'
import { ActivityIndicator } from 'react-native'

const wait = (timeout) => {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, timeout));
} 

const RootElement = () => {
    const [result, setResult] = useState(null)
    getLoginSession().then(data => {
        [loginSessionState, setLoginSessionState] = useState("");
        if (loginSessionState != null) {
            setResult((
                <ThemeProvider>
                    <NavigationContainer >
                        <AppNavigation />
                    </NavigationContainer>
                </ThemeProvider>))
        } else {
            setResult((
                <ThemeProvider>
                    <Login>
                    </Login>
                </ThemeProvider>
            ))
        }
    })
    return result
}

    const App = () => {
    return (
        <Suspense fallback={<ActivityIndicator />}>
            <RootElement />
        </Suspense>
    )   
}

export default App
```

Comment: Add the code for `getLoginSession`. What value do you return from this function?

Comment: It just returns a string or null

import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';

const getLoginSession = async () => {
    try {
      const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@SessionID')
      return value
    } catch(e) {
        return e
    }
  }

export default getLoginSession;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try

```
import { ActivityIndicator } from "react-native";


const RootElement = () => {
  const [loggedIn, setLoggedIn] = useState(false);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      try {
        const data = await getLoginSession();
        if (data != null) {
          setLoggedIn(true);
        }
      } catch (error) {
        setLoggedIn(false);
      }
      setLoading(false);
    })();
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      {!loading ? (
        loggedIn ? (
          <ThemeProvider>
            <NavigationContainer>
              <AppNavigation />
            </NavigationContainer>
          </ThemeProvider>
        ) : (
          <ThemeProvider>
            <Login />
          </ThemeProvider>
        )
      ) : (
        <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#00ff00" />
      )}
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: It worked, thank you so much. Why does it work with useEffect? Does this prevent the component from rendering, while active "jobs" are running?

Comment: @Hagen the code you had in root element would have been called again everytime any component re renders. Also, hooks can only be used inside components itself not inside promise's then. This is how you should check for data if you want to conditionally render components. This is the react way of doing things